# Source code vs DLL

Tags: dll, exe, so

У меня 2 вопроса. Где лучше хранить готовые модули кода? В exe или в dll/so?  Это проприетарный код который не будут использовать другие приложения. С одной стороны лучше в исходниках т.к. подгрузка всех функций идет в CT, но с другой стороны это увеличит размер приложения. Это сильно повлияет на скорость его запуска?

Просто какое бы современное приложение не открыл - везде куча dll/so. Не могут же все ошибаться. Значит лучше в dll-ках? Но опять же вопрос стоит боком т.к. Dll может хранить только RT-совместимый функционал и CT функционал при билде на выходе не участвует. В результате в некоторых случаях одна и та же функция будет иметь меньший размер в exe чем в DLL.

Вопрос 2й - почему все их используют если заранее знают что их dll ками никто кроме приложения разработчика пользоваться не будет.
Если просто хранить часто используемые данные то как по мне лучше в коде сохранять серилизованные данные, а при необходимости их загружать и десерилезовать. Это поидее и более безопасно, более быстро и по необходимости можно расширить функционал "просто данных"

Comment: Source code - не может конкурировать c dll однозначно.

Comment: 2. dll могут вполне быть библиотеками сторонних фирм, например  opengl, directx для графики, есть для проигрывания видеороликов определённого формата в играх и т д. Библиотеки позволяют делать "оверлей", т.е. если программа большая - загружать и выгружать ненужные куски кода.

Comment: 3. Вашей библиотекой врядли кто-то сможет воспользоваться без документации, разве что у вас будут настолько простые аргументы, что это будет очевидно. Но если на вход идёт структура или это функция класса, то не зная какая у вас структура - выковыривать её врядли кто-то будет. Вообще если это не игра, или не защищенная программа вроде shareware хорошего качества, или программой будут пользоваться там до 100 до 1000 человек - то врядли кто будет ваши exe-dll ковырять вообще.

Comment: @nick_n_a , я прекрасно понимаю суть динамических библиотек как оверлея, но как я уже писал ранее что в мой dll загоняется код который будет использоваться только одним приложением. С этой стороны как лучше хранить код - в source или в DLL. По поводу 2го вопроса я имел ввиду не библиотеки общего назначения. Если взять какой нибудь более менее серьезную программу, к примеру, для работы с графикой, то в релизных файлах можно увидеть несколько dll файлов которые явно делались под конкретное приложение

Comment: И если смотреть с этой точки зрения то я не вижу разницы между dll и исходным кодом со стороны импорта функций. За исключением из так скажем типа. Даже если пилить dll под конкретное приложение. Dll не будет сам по себе жить. Я создам лоадер, опишу там нужные функции и загружу символы с DLL. Если мы имеем статическую привязку (либо либ, либо соурс) то по факту мы имеем тоже самое. Только функции уже описаны. Только все. Я же не буду сначала делать либ под приложение и брать оттуда только часть функций. Те которые не нужны можно ли перевести на CT, либо в принципе не импортировать на стороне

Comment: Не хватило места закончит мысль. Со стороны линковщика

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123950/discussion-between-wusiki-jeronii-and-nick-n-a).